# Is this vector field conservative? My team thinks it is conservative, I don't?

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals

Question that we have a disagreement about
[image]

The graph
[image]

My teammates say that the vector field is conservative. But I do not think so, reason being is because if you draw a closed curve on the vector field and add up all the line integrals I believe you get a value greater than zero. For a vector field to be conservative the line integral must equal zero.

So am I correct to say the vector field is not conservative. and So on the question part c it would be none of the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. To see that the vector field is not conservative, it will suffice to demonstrate a loop which has a non-zero line integral. You can pretty easily do this with this vector field by starting at the origin, travelling right along the x-axis, travelling north, then returning to the y-axis, and from there back to the origin. All of the components of this path will have integral $0$, except for the second, which has a positive integral.

Comment: I am having a hard time visualizing your example, but it makes sense that if your example produces a positive integral it cannot be conservative. So to sum it up the vector field is not conservative?

Comment: Here's a quick MSPaint of the path to help you. https://imgur.com/eDOYowu Obviously, all of the components should be straight lines.

Comment: And so when it is traveling in the same direction, but overlapping, like in your second one, the fact that it is overlapping does not make it 0? It is still an acute angle formed which is > 0 for the integral?

Comment: @Dporth Pretend only the red path I've drawn is there. It only "picks up" any value during the climb upwards on the right hand side of the square. On the other legs it's travelling perpendicular to the vector field, or the vector field is 0, so no value is being added to the integral.

Comment: Follow up, If you add the line integral over the curve C1 to the line integral C2 wouldn't you get 0? But this does not impact whether or not it is conservative because C1 and C2 are not the same curve?

Comment: @Dporth You're right that following $C_1$ and then $C_2$ (backwards) will give you a $0$ line integral. However, for a vector field to be conservative, we need *every* (reasonable) path to have a $0$ line integral. Because I have found a path with a non-zero line integral, the field is not conservative.

Comment: so if you did not find that path, your allowed to use two different curves C1 and C2 traveling in a different direction in part of your determination for whether or not it is conservative? In other words, even though they are two different curves you have to consider them as a whole?

Comment: @Dporth Sure. As long as the endpoints match up, you can compose two paths. Just don't forget if you're travelling "backwards" along a path, because if you are, the sign will be opposite.

Comment: Here is an image I drew, does this further prove it is not a conservative vector field? https://imgur.com/a/3UO9n

Comment: @Dporth It's hard to tell, but I do not think so, as it looks like that curve will have a line integral of $0$.

Comment: but F dot dr should be greater than zero. I because all of the vectors are going with the tangent vectors of the red curve.

Comment: @Dporth Oh, pardon me, yes, you're correct.

Comment: Yay awesome, I feel relieved, thank you @Duncan I have learned A LOT from this little bit, and feel a lot more confident for my final in calc 3 monday

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that the $y$ component of the vector field is proportional to $x$, i.e. the vector field looks a bit like $0dx+xdy$.

That one does not satisfy any of (a)-(c) because the necessary condition for a vector field $f (x,y)dx+g (x,y)dy $ to satisfy those conditions is $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac {\partial g}{\partial x} $, which is not the case here ($0\ne 1$).

Thus my guess is that the vector field from the problem also does not satisfy (a)-(c).